# Hibernate Spring connection Could not autowire

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to do some crud operation on a OracleDB with Hibernate and Spring.
I generated the class with HibernateTools. I create an Interface like this:

```
public interface AssegniDao {

}
```

and an implementation like this

```
@Repository
@Qualifier("AssegniDao")
public class AssegnoDaoImpl extends AbstractAutowiredDao implements AssegniDao { 

}
```

This is all in a project called "dataLayer". From an other project I tested it with Junit but I have all the time this kind of error

> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field

How can I solve this?

### Edit

Full stack trace

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [it.bnl.btre.orchass.busin.dao.AssegniDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=AssegniDao)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:948)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:817)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:731)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)

Comment: Please post the full error, not just a random infix.

Comment: Spring expects beans in camel case. So, replace `AssegniDao` in `@Qualifier` annoatation to `assegniDao` and try

Comment: Tried but no success

Comment: Please post your configuraiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to scan the packages first:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="the.path.to.your.package.with.controller" />
```

Name the bean with:

```
@Repository("AssegnoDao")
public class AssegnoDaoImpl extends AbstractAutowiredDao implements AssegniDao { 

}
```

Then, when you use `@Autowire`, don't forget to specity the name of the bean:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("AssegniDao")
private AssegniDao assegniDao;
```

Comment: The same of before :(

Comment: I posted the trace in EDIT1